# String to Int showing error: Format of input string is not correct.. in CS file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got stuck in this error...

```
<a id="25" class="abc" href="example.aspx" onclick="return myfunction(this);">
```

and my function code take id of this link and save it to session variable..

```
function myfunction(a)
{
  var myid = a.id;
  '<%Session["x"] ="' + myid +'";%>';
  return;
}
```

so, after that it will redirect example.aspx and throwimg code for example.aspx.cs file is:

```
static int j = 0;
if(Session["x"]!=null)
{
   j = int.Parse(Session["x"].ToString());
}
```

this line throwing error:
FormatException: Format of input string is not correct..

stack:

```
[FormatException: Format of input string is not correct..]
System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +7476983
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
   System.Int32.Parse(String s) +23
   example.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in example.aspx.cs:103
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: it should return 25 as a string .. because we have stored it from javascript function

Comment: when i added alert to javascript function of session["x"] than it returned correct 25.. but i dont know in that page what it actually returns...can you tell me how can i know that? pls

Comment: what happend if you put '<%Session["x"] =" + myid +";%>';

Comment: My guess is that `Session["x"]` is blank, can you check?

Comment: than it will not take myid as variable....

Comment: Also, you can't use Javascript to update your backend. Javascript runs on the client in the browser.

Comment: ok.. but when i set alert('<%=Session["x"]%>'); than it is showing correct value

Comment: I also tried this with __dopostback.. but same result..

Comment: Session["x'] working in first page where we assigned it.. but not working after page redirects..

Comment: You're completely misunderstood what session variables are. The *only* way you can update a *session* variable from the client is by making a request to your server. The code you've written in `myfunction` will absolutely *not* execute code on your server.

Comment: i have tried it with __dopostback as well but same result.. also when i tried to save it like string a = session["x"]; on cs page than error: Can not implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. There is an explicit conversion. Likely to cast missing.

Comment: yes, session[] is an array of objects. you need to explicitly cast it to an appropriate type

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is essentially that `'<% ... %>'` is used **only** when server(i.e. .cs ) sends data to clientside ( i.e. .html, .js).

To pass data from client side to server, you need to use other alternatives like [Query Strings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString) or html `<form>` tag.